# Is there an event raised when a message is dequeued from an MSMQ queue?

Tags: .net, msmq

I'm trying to get a level of management information available in a system which is being driven by MSMQ queues. I want to know if there's an event which can be listened to, to know when a message is successfully dequeued from a queue.

Ideally the event would be consumed via a .NET application.

This would allow me to keep track of the volume of messages passing through a queue without implementing logic into the receiving service endpoint and enable common mechanisms regardless of receiver (which will be BizTalk in some cases).

Comment: No, just raise your own event when you dequeue a message.  If this is another app then double-no, events don't work across process boundaries.

Comment: @Hans Passant, BizTalk won't raise an event when it's reading from a message queue. The COM events should work cross-process (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms705317(v=vs.85).aspx), but I don't have the experience to know if the right event for me is available.

Answer (score 1):

The `MessageQueue.BeginReceive` asynchronous method raises the [ReceivedCompleted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.messaging.messagequeue.receivecompleted.aspx) event when a message has been sucessfully received (and therefore removed from a queue).

Comment: My application is not calling `BeginReceive`, instead consuming the messages through an WCF binding on a .NET service or a BizTalk adapter.